# Python itertools.product challenge to expand a dict with tuples

Tags: python, python-itertools

Given a dictionary like this with some items being tuples...

```
params = {
 'a': 'static',
 'b': (1, 2),
 'c': ('X', 'Y')
}
```

I need the "product" of the items into a list of dict like this, with the tuples expanded so each item in b will be matched with each item in c...

```
[{ 'a': 'static', 'b': 1, 'c': 'X' },
 { 'a': 'static', 'b': 1, 'c': 'Y' },
 { 'a': 'static', 'b': 2, 'c': 'X' },
 { 'a': 'static', 'b': 2, 'c': 'Y')}]
```

I can easily separate the initial input into a list of non-tuple items and tuple items, and apply the key of each tuple to the values as a "tag" prior to multiplication so they look like this: `'b##1', 'b##2', 'c##X', 'c##Y'`. Then parse those back into the above dict after multiplication. If I would always see 2 tuple items (like b and c), I could easily pass both to `itertools.products`. But there could be 0..n tuple items, and `product()` doesn't multiply a list of lists in this way. Can anyone think of a solution?

```
TAG = '##'      
# separate tuples and non-tuples from the input, and prepend the key of each tuple as a tag on the value to parse out later
for key, value in params.items():
    if type(value) is tuple:
        for x in value:
            tuples.append(f'{key}{TAG}{x}')
    else:
        non_tuples.append({key: value})
print(list(product(tuples))      # BUG: doesn't distribute each value of b with each value of c
```

Comment: Would you mind [edit]ing the title of your question to something that better describes the actual problem? This makes it easier for people searching for the same thing to find your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`product` takes multiple iterables, but the key thing to remember is that an iterable can contain a single item. In cases where a value in your original dict isn't a tuple (or maybe a list), you want to convert it to a tuple containing a single value and pass that to `product`:

```
params_iterables = {}
for k, v in params.items():
    if isinstance(v, (tuple, list)):
        params_iterables[k] = v     # v is already a tuple or a list
    else:
        params_iterables[k] = (v, ) # A tuple containing a single value, v
```

which gives:

```
params_iterables = {'a': ('static',), 'b': (1, 2), 'c': ('X', 'Y')}
```

Then, simply get the product of the values in `params_iterables`:

```
result = []
for values in product(*params_iterables.values()):
    result.append(dict(zip(params, values)))
```

The `dict(zip(params, values))` line creates a dict where the first element of `values` is assigned the first key in `params`, and so on. This dict is then appended to `result`, which gives the desired output:

```
[{'a': 'static', 'b': 1, 'c': 'X'},
 {'a': 'static', 'b': 1, 'c': 'Y'},
 {'a': 'static', 'b': 2, 'c': 'X'},
 {'a': 'static', 'b': 2, 'c': 'Y'}]
```

Comment: Excellent @pho. I really appreciate your comments. I understand how you and Andrej did it now.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
from itertools import product

params = {"a": "static", "b": (1, 2), "c": ("X", "Y")}


out = []
for vals in product(
    *[v if isinstance(v, (tuple, list)) else (v,) for v in params.values()]
):
    out.append(dict(zip(params, vals)))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"a": "static", "b": 1, "c": "X"},
    {"a": "static", "b": 1, "c": "Y"},
    {"a": "static", "b": 2, "c": "X"},
    {"a": "static", "b": 2, "c": "Y"},
]
```

---

One-liner:

```py
out = [
    dict(zip(params, vals))
    for vals in product(
        *(v if isinstance(v, (tuple, list)) else (v,) for v in params.values())
    )
]
```

Comment: That's wicked amazing Andrej!

Comment: Nice one @AndrejKesely.  I was on the heels of your one-liner. You beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 0):

The obvious itertools.product solution was already posted, so here's a fast alternative. Expands one param at a time ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBDoIwEEX3PcXs2iaVRFeGxHtoCAssEBukbWBoQggnccNG7-QlPIOtVDf-5Zs__2fm9rAjXoxelvuA9Wb_fNmiK9oeDjAR8KIFTYH2WKCSVKzo7BHbCtjxCGQA9EgF0BPlZCbEDOgjsmnOSW06aAQ4UBrW8ERh1faMp59tVYM2CKpX2tdoWTEnAAd7raIhyPk0t7bF6DKRxo6M_yxeoaoMPd7zx7MmDyOXE2I7pZF5E1-vjsd_n_AG)):

```py
params = {
    'a': 'static',
    'b': (1, 2),
    'c': ('X', 'Y')
}

out = [{}]
for k, v in params.items():
    if not isinstance(v, tuple):
        v = v,
    out = [d.copy()
           for d in out
           for d[k] in v]

print(out)
```

Times for three cases:

```
19 parameters with 2 options each:
  0.75 seconds  no_comment
  1.26 seconds  Andrej

10 parameters with 4 options each:
  0.60 seconds  no_comment
  1.63 seconds  Andrej

6 parameters with 10 options each:
  0.46 seconds  no_comment
  1.18 seconds  Andrej
```

Benchmark script:

```py
from itertools import product
from time import time
from string import ascii_lowercase

params = {c: (i, -i) for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase[:19])}
params = {c: tuple(range(4)) for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase[:10])}

def no_comment(params):
    out = [{}]
    for k, v in params.items():
        if not isinstance(v, tuple):
            v = v,
        out = [d.copy()
               for d in out
               for d[k] in v]
    return out

def Andrej(params):
    return [
        dict(zip(params, vals))
        for vals in product(
            *(v if isinstance(v, (tuple, list)) else (v,) for v in params.values())
        )
    ]

print(no_comment(params) == Andrej(params))

for f in [no_comment, Andrej] * 3:
    t0 = time()
    f(params)
    print(time() - t0, f.__name__)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVOxTsMwEB3Y8gdsNzoorYpggEod-I4oiiznUkxjO7IvQaXql7B0gY_ia7DjtCWFAU_23fN7987n9892S89GHw4fHdWzh6-r69oaBZLQkjGNA6laYwlaa6pOUDJkSSo8JsI-Rh1ZqdfHOHdCyrIxr2gFd5gkLbdcOVjBTiyByQxmMoXaWPBbAVID6k6h5YTs4m6-vH0s0v2Ugbq2QWa5XiO7T__PtAhMSYU1aFMKoxRqYpE5XSbgl-nIa-S7fTEcA_Emgz4QR9zcd0c5NsLDkoGNQDqpHXEtkPVZrPAHKKzeM_fZKTRKVXNh2i1LJ9BRugq6HvdnLt8UId3HSi1SZyN4MPikK4svU3MjJj_RVVIQe5PtCPNGeePScylBJ4QG-3EI2KSWG9YH_1PvbDCfQSMd-cfBxiH4eHymn6301B36Xp4F467wA-PHidjvV4LV6sJamiSBtw68-flCNsIKuIG7aJ8Wvt9hZMdm10eK4RQVYxpmHpxBPS9LzRWWZRp_yPhRjh_mGw)

A possible optimization is hidden in a markdown comment, view the answer's source to see it.

Comment: Please let me know what the issue is, so I can address it.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what's happening but I'm really surprised that a solution that seems to iterate over every element in `out` is faster than one that simply appends new elements to `out`

Comment: @pho Let "k-dict" mean a dict for the first k params. My code builds the list of (k+1)-dicts from the list of k-dicts. It does that by expanding each k-dict with all options of the (k+1)-th parameter. Single-key modifications and dict copying are faster than building a dict from scratch from key/value pairs. (Exception: This can be slower if the last few params have only one option, as I'm making some not strictly needed copies and that hurts in such cases. That could be optimized, but I'd rather keep it simple. I only added the benchmark in case someone thought this is generally slow.)

Comment: @pho I added an optimized version in a hidden comment in the answer. In the tested case, Andrew's was faster than my original, but my optimized version is fastest. I only optimized params where there's only one option, by making zero copies instead of one. I could generally make len(v)-1 copies instead of len(v), but meh...